# "Plugging into" conditional probability - why does it work?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-verification, conditional-expectation

I think the best way to ask this question is using an example.

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable and $Y$ a (not necessarily continuous) random variable that is independent of $X.$ Consider the following proof that $P(X=Y)=0.$

> Write
>   $$P(X=Y) = E[P(X=Y|Y)] = E[E(1_{\{X=Y\}}|Y)] = E[E(Z|Y)], \tag{1}$$
>   where $Z=1_{\{X=Y\}}.$
>
> By the [factorization lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_lemma), there exists a measurable function $g$ such that $E(Z|Y) = g(Y)$ (almost surely). One often writes $E(Z|Y=y):= g(y).$ Now, for any $y\in \bar{\mathbb R}$ it holds that 
>   \begin{align}
> g(y)&=E(Z|Y=y)\\
> &= P(X=Y|Y=y)\text{ (by $(1)$) }\\
> &=P(X=y|Y=y) \tag{2}\\
> &=P(X=y) \text{ (by independence) } \tag{3}\\
> &=0 \text{ (since $X$ is a continuous r.v.) }
> \end{align}
>
> This implies that $P(X=Y|Y)=0$ a.s. and hence $P(X=Y) = E[P(X=Y|Y)] = 0.$

**Question: Why is step $(2)$ valid? (is it?)**

Why can we plug $Y=y$ into the probability? This is "notationally obvious", but I'm looking for a rigorous explanation.

**Edit:** Thinking about this, I'm also unsure about $(3).$ The probability of $Y=y$ might be zero so independence doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

The random variables $X$ and $Y$ are measurable functions $X,Y\colon \Omega\to\mathbb R$ on the probability space $\Omega$. Let $\mathcal F\subseteq 2^\Omega$ denote the the $\sigma$-algebra of measurable events and recall that the probability measure is a map $P\colon\mathcal F\to[0,1]$ and things like $X=Y$ and $Y=y$ are just shorthand notations for the events $\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)=Y(\omega)\}$ and $\{\omega\in\Omega : Y(\omega)=y\}=Y^{-1}(y)$, respectively.

The "substitution" you mention boils down to the following equality of subsets of $\Omega$:
$$
\bigg((X=Y)\cap(Y=y)\bigg) = \bigg( (X=y) \cap (Y=y) \bigg).
$$

Indeed, both are equal to $\{\omega\in\Omega : X(\omega)=Y(\omega)=y\}$.

Regardless of how exactly you define $P(\,-\,|\,Y=y\,)$ in case that $Y=y$ has measure zero, it will be a probability measure on $Y=y$ (that is, on the subspace $Y^{-1}(y)\subseteq\Omega$). Let $X|_{Y=y}$ and $Y|_{Y=y}$ denote the restrictions of $X$ and $Y$ to that subspace, then the above equality becomes an equality of measurable subsets of $Y=y$:
$$
\bigg(X|_{Y=y} = Y|_{Y=y}\bigg) = \bigg(X|_{Y=y} = y\bigg).
$$

Hence, both sets have the same measure under $P(\,-\,|\,Y=y\,)$.

Comment: This works if $P(Y=y)>0.$ Is there a way to save this, if $P(Y=y)=0?$

Comment: What is your definition of $P(A|B)$ in that case? I edited my answer to reflect the important step. This equality of events holds in any case.

Comment: The definition I use is from the factorization lemma (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_lemma):

$P(X=Y|Y=y):=E(1_{\{X=Y\}}|Y=y):=g(y),$ where $g$ is the measurable function with $E(1_{\{X=Y\}}|Y)=g(Y) \text{ a.s.}$ whose existence is guaranteed by the factorization lemma.

Since this definition depends on the random variable $1_{\{X=Y\}}$ I don't know how we can plug arbitrary events into the argument. If this is not possible, how can the conditional probability be a probability measure on $\{Y=y\}\cap \mathcal F$?

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer to your question, but a more convenient route that leads to $P(X=Y)=0$ in this context.

Let it be that for $x,y\in\mathbb R$ we have:

- $[x=y]=1$ if $x=y$ and $[x=y]=0$ otherwise.

Then because $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $X$ has continuous distribution we have:

$$P(X=Y)=\mathbb E[X=Y]=\int\int[x=y]F_X(x)F_Y(y)=\int P(X=y)F_Y(y)=\int0F_Y(y)=0$$

---

Concerning your question about step 2:

Troubles arise if we define: $P(A\mid B):=P(A\cap B)/P(B)$ because a denominator appears that might equal $0$.

In my view it is better to  define $P(A\mid B)$ indirectly by stating that $p=P(A\mid B)$ whenever $p\times P(B)=P(A\cap B)$.

Then if indeed $P(B)=0$ there are several candidates for $p$ and we can pick out the one that is most suitable (and corresponds with our intuition).

In this context note that:

$P(X=Y\mid Y=y)P(Y=y)$ and $P(X=y\mid Y=y)P(Y=y)$ both equalize $$P(X=Y\wedge Y=y)=P(X=y\wedge Y=y)$$